How to prove that in a geometry with no parallel lines, all the lines must be finite in length?
In the Veritasium video on the fifth Euclidean postulate, there was a statement (link with a timecode) that mathematicians (before discovering spherical geometry) managed to prove that in a geometry with no parallel lines (probably assuming all the Euclidean postulates except the second and the fifth hold), the lines must be finite in length.
That is indeed true for the spherical geometry, since the great circles, considered to be analogous to straight lines in the Euclidean geometry, by definition, intersect. Even though I am not a mathematician, I tried to prove the statement and, as expected, I failed. I searched for the proof, but could not find one.
Does the absence of parallel lines indeed imply that all the lines in the geometry are finite?
If so, how it can be proven?
